# Dynamic Featured Image - WordPress - is not getting the first featured image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I've installed the latest Dynamic Featured Image 3.1.2 and when I try to just print out the array of featured images on the page I only get Featured Image 2 and onward.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {
        global $dynamic_featured_image;
        $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images( );

        print_r( $featured_images );

        //You can now loop through the image to display them as required
    } ?>

    ... << rest of Post Loop >>
```

Even though I've added more than one Featured image it only shows from Featured Image 2 and on in the array.

Did I miss something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing in your code are the *custom* Featured Images (Featured Image 2 onwards) added by the plugin Dynamic Featured Image 3.1.2:

```
<?php if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {...
```

..while the first "Featured Image" in your Edit post screen is implemented in the wordpress core itself and can be printed using the `the_post_thumbnail` function (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all featured images including the default WordPress one using this function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve featured images for specific post(s) 
 * including the default Featured Image
 *
 * @since 3.1.2
 * @access public
 *
 * @see  $this->get_featured_images()
 *
 * @param Integer $post_id id of the current post
 *
 * @return Array An array of images or an empty array on failure
 */
public function get_all_featured_images( $post_id = null ) {

    if ( is_null( $post_id ) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

    $featured_image_array = array();
    if ( ! empty( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        $featured_image = array(
            'thumb' => wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $thumbnail_id ),
            'full' => wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ),
            'attachment_id' => $thumbnail_id
        );
        $featured_image_array[] = $featured_image;
    }

    $dfiImages = $this->get_featured_images( $post_id );

    $all_featured_images = array_merge( $featured_image_array, $dfiImages );

    return $all_featured_images;

}
```

This function will be included in plugin in the next release. Till then you can add it to your `dynamic-featured-image.php` plugin file or you can download the and use the file from the [master branch](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/Dynamic-Featured-Image/archive/master.zip) of github.

P.S. I am the author of the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/).

Comment: There is a cache problem or something with this function. I was using it with `full` than I needed to use cropped images. Didn't found no ways to do that so I was switched to `thumb`. As default thumb in wordpress was 150x150. Changed to 400x300 and did a regenerate of thumbnails and links are still at 150x150. Removed old 150x150 too, did another regenerate and now I have broken links..